# How to use keybindings containing @ in MacOS X?

Tags: key-bindings, osx, aquamacs

I'm using Aquamacs 2.x in MacOS X 10.6.
(I'm using the Command key as M and the Ctrl key as C.)

WHen I try to use keybindings containing "@", it does not work, e. g. `C-c @ C-t` in `outline-minor-mode`.

I can type the @ sign in Aquamacs buffers with Alt-L.

But when I try to hit
Ctrl-C, Alt-L, I get the message "^C ⌘L is undefined" even before I can add Ctrl-t

EDIT:
it seems that I can use the Alt key and the Command key as well as META-Key, which is not necessary. I only want to use the Command key as META (to be "compatible" with WIndows and UNIX computers).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Aquamacs, I had the Option `...Meta & German` activated, which seemed to be the problem.

Now with another setting, I can enter also commands which contain the @ sign.

We'll see, if there are some side effects...